# Specify type of a vector/array containing any number

Tags: julia

Brand new to Julia - so I apologize for the simple question, just couldn't seem to find the answer anywhere:

I am trying to create a function which takes a vector as an argument, but enforces that the vector contains numbers (either floats or ints).

I feel like this should be written as:

```
function foo(x::Vector{Number})
    return x.^2
end
```

But running this with `foo([5.0])` yields

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
   foo(::Array{Number,1}) at REPL[16]:2
```

Why is this? I don't want to resort to saying `x::Vector`, which would work, but doesn't provide the type-checking enforcement that I would want.

Comment: The answer by DNF is correct, but note additionally it is preferred to use `AbstractVector` for function argument types, not `Vector`, unless you have good reason otherwise. The code in the answer will fail on `foo(1:4)`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write

```
function foo(x::Vector{T}) where {T<:Number}
    return x.^2
end
```

A shorthand notation for this is

```
function foo(x::Vector{<:Number})
    return x.^2
end
```

**Edit:** Based on comments by @Liso and @MichaelKBorregaard I suggest the following, which disallows `Complex` and allows `AbstractVector`s:

```
function foo(x::AbstractVector{<:Real})
    return x.^2
end
```

If you *really* only want to allow floats and ints, you can do:

```
function foo(x::AbstractVector{<:Union{AbstractFloat, Integer}})
    return x.^2
end
```

You can get pretty much as specific or as general as you like.

Comment: If OP want to support only floats and ints (and not `Complex` for example)  then maybe better to replace `Number` with `Real`